# Can dust or humidity affect the shift mechanism of a sensor stabilised camera?

Tags: sensor, pentax, image-stabilization, sony-alpha

Sony and Pentax, and probably others, use a shift mechanism in the sensor (movable sensor) for image stabilization.

While I see many benefits with this approach, how are these sensors protected against dust and humidity? Are these cameras more susceptible to the sensor sticking (somehow), and if so, without the user noticing?

Comment: As water and sand could be described by humidity and dust, I would that yes, it can definitively damage your camera.
Have you such a problem? ([XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ?)

Comment: @Olivier No, I do not have such a problem. I am just wondering if sensors with shift mechanism are more prone to errors caused by dust or similar than conventional sensors.

Answer (score 2):

Dust and humidity can be an issue with any camera, those that are weatherproof, when used with a suitable weatherproof lens, have less of a problem.

The presence of a sensor-shift stabilization has no impact. What you should know is that the majority of cameras have a mechanism to shake the sensor which in fact used to remove dust! Others shake the sensor to compensate for movement, simulate an anti-alias filter or capture super-resolution. This adds features and obviously requires more movement latitude but most sensors do move. There are a few cameras which have a fixed sensor and use a hot-filter in front of the sensor to prevent dust from entering the sensor area.

Comment: Also, you'd probably have your camera send in for cleaning before there's enough dust in there to damage the mechanism, to get rid of the dark spots in your images.

Comment: At least all of Canon's "self cleaning" sensors don't move the sensor at all. They move the filter stack in front of the sensor.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "Yes." But if you are getting enough dust or humidity inside your camera to cause that problem, then you have **WAY** bigger problems to worry about. If you are even reasonably careful when changing lenses, then you will only get one or two specks of dust inside your camera every year or so. And those will all land on your sensor or somewhere where it won't matter. In fact, the motion of the sensor while stabilizing the image tends to knock off dust from the sensor, unless you are just flinging mud in there.